# convergence in probability and mean square

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

We have a sequence of independent random variables defined as
$Y_n= a+n$ with probability $\frac{1}{n}$ and $Y_n=a$ with probability $1-\frac{1}{n}$.

1. Does the sequence converge in probability?
2. Does the sequence converge in [mean square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_mean) sense?

If it is convergent in either sense, what's the limit?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $X_n=Y_n-a$. Then $P(|X_n|\geq 1)=\frac 1n$, so what can you deduce about convergence in probability?

We have $E[X_n^2]=(a+n)^2/n+a^2(1-1/n)$, so $E[X_n^2]$ is not bounded.